# How do you modify an Abstract Data Type(ADT) stack?

Tags: java, stack, abstract-data-type

Using the stack interface definition, what string is at the top of the stack and what string is at the bottom?

I know the .push method just adds the selected item to the top of the stack, but what I'm having trouble with is when there is a pop method within a push method or when there is a peek method within a push method.

I also need help on the line that says String name = stringStack.pop();

```
StackInterface<String> stringStack = new MyStack<>(); 

stringStack.push( “Jane” ); 
stringStack.push( “Jess” ); 
stringStack.push( “Jill” ); 
stringStack.push( stringStack.pop()); 
stringStack.push( stringStack.peek()); 
stringStack.push( “Jim” ); 
String name = stringStack.pop(); 
stringStack.push( stringStack.peek());
```

I expect the order to be:

TOP Jim Jim Jill Jill Jess Jane BOTTOM

Comment: No: Jim is not in the stack after you pop it off.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you Maurice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation like this:

```
stringStack.push( stringStack.pop());
```

You just have to keep in mind that `push` has to know what value to push, before the value is pushed. How does it know what value to push? Evaluating `pop()`, of course! So an item is popped first, then `push` knows what item to push, and pushes to back. In other words, A `pop` inside a `push` overall does nothing to the stack.

What about:

```
stringStack.push( stringStack.peek());
```

Instead of popping the top item off and then pushing it, this will only *look at* the top item, and then pushes it onto the stack. So overall this is just "copying" the top item.

Here is what the stack looks like after each line (left is the top):

```
stringStack.push( “Jane” ); 
// Jane
stringStack.push( “Jess” ); 
// Jess Jane
stringStack.push( “Jill” ); 
// Jill Jess Jane
stringStack.push( stringStack.pop()); 
// Jill Jess Jane
stringStack.push( stringStack.peek()); 
// Jill Jill Jess Jane
stringStack.push( “Jim” ); 
// Jim Jill Jill Jess Jane
String name = stringStack.pop(); 
// Jill Jill Jess Jane
stringStack.push( stringStack.peek());
// Jill Jill Jill Jess Jane
```